# Why is contact form not sending email to client?

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts, spam

When I change the email to my personal hotmail address, the message turns up - although it is in my spam folder. But when I change this to the client's email, the message doesn't turn up at all. Does anybody know how I can fix this?

This is the PHP for the form:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = 'Message from Reef Cleaning solutions website';
$to = 'info@address.co.uk';

if (empty($name) || empty($address) || empty($number) || empty($email) || empty($subject) || empty($message)) {
    if (empty($name))
        $error['name'] = "Please enter your Full Name";
    if (empty($address))
        $error['address'] = "Please enter your address";
    if (empty($number))
        $error['number'] = "Please enter a contact number";
    if (empty($email))
        $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid Email Address";
    if (empty($message))
        $error['message'] = "Please write a message, enquiries or other concerns above";
}
else { //if not empty
    $body = "
    Name: $name\r\n
    Address: $address\r\n
    Number: $number\r\n
    Email: $email\r\n
    Message: $message
    ";

    $headers="From: {$email}\r\nReply-To: {$email}"; //create headers for email

    if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers))
    {
      $success = "mail has been sent";
    }
    else
    {
     echo "error during sending mail";
    }
}
}
?>
```

This is the HTML

```
 <form method="POST">
       <table border="1">
            <tr>
            <td><label for="name" class="g">Name</label></td>
            <td><input id="name" name="name" type="text" autofocus required /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td><label for="address" class="g">Address</label></td>
            <td><textarea rows="3" id="address" name="address" cols="50"></textarea></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td><label for="number" class="g">Contact number</label></td>
            <td><input id="number" name="number" type="text" autofocus required /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td><label for="email" class="g">Email</label></td>
            <td><input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="example@domain.com" autofocus required /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td><label for="message" class="g">Enquiry</label></td>
            <td><textarea rows="3" id="message" name="message" required cols="50"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />

            <div id="message-sent"> 
            <?php
            if ($success) {
                echo $success;
            }
            ?>
            </div>

            </form>
```

Comment: If it appears in your spam folder, it's being sent; therefore its an issue client side

Comment: I think he is saying that if he send the email to a hotmail account the email is sent and goes in the spam folder in hotmail. If he send the email to info@address.co.uk the email is not sent. But.. do you get any error? I mean, the email is sent and rejected by your client or the mail is not sent at all? are you able to at least detect that? The HTML form is good, even the code seems good.

Comment: I'm using outitgoes.com to test the client email address and nothing is showing up in this inbox or spam folder. 

However, when I test it on my personal hotmail, it does turn up in my email.

Comment: Just to clarify God's statement - if the only thing that has changed is the receipient address then it's nothing to do with the PHP/HTML. If you look at the frequent question regarding php's mail() command, it's very rarely a problem with PHP - usually it's the mail config. Have you checked your MTA log / bounces?

Comment: do you have a spam folder in this outitgoes.com?  In addition to that, are you sure you made the exact same test? I mean, exact same object and email contenct? be sure to respect all other constraints http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php regarding subject and content.

Comment: ....and I don't see anything helpful in Madthew's comment

Comment: Is there a way of correctly altering the php with smtp headers so it doesn't get flagged as spam?

How does everyone else combat this issue?

Comment: This as been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666323/php-e-mail-to-spam

Answer (score 0):

If you receive the message on your email, it's not a problem from the PHP code, because it successfully send mail.

So, is the configured email correct ? Can you send email to this address with your personnal address ?

You tell the email is considered as a spam on your personnal address, maybe it's the same thing for this other address, but the message dont fall in a "spam" folder, but is not allowed to enter to mailbox.